# Pointers On C exercises 6.18-2, my solution does not work

Tags: c, pointers, substr, del

I'm a c beginer. learning C via the book ,below is my solution to 6.18-2 write a fucton to delete substr from source string.It does not work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *find_char(char const *source, char const *chars)
{
    int offset = 0;

    if (source == NULL || chars == NULL || *source == '\0' || *chars == '\0')
        return NULL;
    
    while (*chars != '\0')
    {
        while (*(source + offset) != '\0')
            if (*(source + offset++) == *chars)
                return source + --offset;

        chars++;
        offset = 0;
    }

    return NULL;
}

int del_substr(char *str, char const *substr)
{
    int offset = 0;
    int suboffset = 0;

    if (str == NULL || substr == NULL)
        return 0;
    while(*(str + offset) != '\0')
    {
        while( *(str + offset) != '\0' && *(str + offset++) == *(substr + suboffset++));
        if(*(substr + suboffset) == '\0')
        {
            while ((*(str + offset - suboffset) = *(str + offset++)) != '\0')
            ;
            return 1;
        }
        offset++;
        suboffset = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    char *source = "hello, people.";
    char *chars = "peo";

    del_substr(source, chars);
    printf("result:%s\n", source);

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: `char source[] = "hello, people.";` gives you a modifiable array.

Comment: @badii If you're not asking about the warning then why include it? The warning is probably trying to tell you that you have some undefined behavior in your program. Ignore it at your own peril.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @badii. I reverted your last edit. Please don't post the answer to your question as part of the question itself. Stack Overflow is a "Q&A" site. The answers are given below. If one of the answers is correct, you should mark it as accepted (you already did, that's good). If the answers are not good (enough) and you have found the solution yourself, you may even post an answer to your own question. But please don't change the question after you've received a correct answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Both `source` and `chars` are pointers to string literals, you can't modify a string literal, as per the language rules, the behavior of a program where this is done is undefined. `source` must be declared as a char array:

```
char source[] = "hello, people.";
```

This way a *copy* of the string is stored in the array and, as such, it is modifiable.

I'm going to guess that your book must talk about string literals and how you should handle them. If that is not the case, we can't really call it *the book*.

Answer (score 0):

You may not change a string literal. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

So in main you need to use the declaration

```
char source[] = "hello, people.";
```

instead of

```
char *source = "hello, people.";
```

Statements like this

```
while( *(str + offset) != '\0' && *(str + offset++) == *(substr + suboffset++));
```

where there is read the variable offset and at the same time is used the postfix increment operator invoke undefined behavior.

This increment

```
offset++;
```

skips many characters. You need to write

```
offset = offset - suboffset + 1;
```